# No signs of life, motherboard and PSU seem ok

Tags: hardware-failure

My computer does nothing when they power button is pressed. No fans even budge.

All cable are in right place and used only the minimal components.

When shorting the green PSU cable to black the PSU comes on, shorting the motherboard power pins does nothing.

motherboard light comes on and USB devices light up

Replace motherboard with the same exact results.

Am all out of ideas to what this could be.

Comment: Could we have more information about your hardware?

Comment: Have you tried using a different PSU? Its possible that its damaged, but can still provide power on certain cables, or provides some voltages that are way off. You could get a multimeter and check the voltages and so on.

Comment: Hardware is phenom 9550, asus sli motherboard on both. 2 250 gfx not hooked up, 4gb ram. I own a multi meter and will check voltage

Comment: Have no different PSU to try, used mutli meter, green wire gives a perfect 3 volts, the rest of the wires give nothing at all un pluged from the board and pluged in only give .45 volts. I can also no longer keep the power supply on by shorting the green wire

Comment: Just tried the multi meter on my brothers PSU to check what power I should get. My purple wire gives me 5v just like his, so I still doubt it is the PSU, plugged it into his motherboard and it turns my power supply on

Comment: Managed to pull out my brothers PSU and it started my computer, must be it :( an I already spent 70 on a new motherboard ugh.